# Define Windows and Linux VM in one resource?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I want to create two VMs with Terraform, one Windows and one Linux server.

I wonder if it is possible to do this using only one resource `"azurerm_virtual_machine" (using count=2)`.

Problem:

My Windows VM needs a `"os_profile_windows_config {}"` section and my Linux VM needs a `"os_profile_linux_config {}"` section. AFAIK Terraform doesn't support `if/else` statements so I'm not sure if this is possible at all.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

While Terraform doesn't have explicit if/else statements, you could use something like this: https://blog.gruntwork.io/terraform-tips-tricks-loops-if-statements-and-gotchas-f739bbae55f9
Those can get quite complex to maintain though...

Comment: Thanks for that hint, but `count` only applies to a resource, not a (sub)element of the resource.